# Cycloid of Ceva - going from polar to parametric curve

Tags: curves, polar-coordinates, parametric, cycloid

Ceva Cycloid polar coordinates form is:
$$
r = 1 + 2\cos(2\phi)
$$

I found that the relation between polar and Cartesian coordinates can be expressed:

$$
x = r\cos\phi, y = r\sin\phi
$$

I need to express Ceva Curve as a parametric equation of the form:
$$
a(t) = (f(t), g(t))
$$

The purpose is that I can draw Ceva Curve as a raster image, programmatically. $a(t)$ could be treated as function of time.

I'd be very grateful for instructions.

Cycloid of Ceva:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that it should be $r = 1 + {\color{red}2}\cos(2\phi)$.
Simply take
$$
a(t)=(r(t)\cos t,r(t)\sin t),
$$
with
$$
r(t)=1 + 2\cos(2t).
$$